# Why is TestRestTemplate ignoring a 404 client error?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-boot, integration-testing

I've written a Spring Boot controller that listens for PUT requests sent to `/orders/`.

In my integration tests, I noticed `TestRestTemplate` is not reacting to a 404 response with an exception as I expected. This leads to a test like this passing:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class OrderControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;


    @Test
    public void testValidPut() throws Exception {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("{}", headers);
        restTemplate.put("/doesntexist", entity);
    }
}
```

when I would have expected the `put` method to throw an exception, as explained in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client/TestRestTemplate.html#put-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-):

> **Throws:**
>   RestClientException - on-client side HTTP error

I've confirmed that if I run my application normally, I get a 404 when attempting to PUT to the same URL.

So either I'm *not* getting a 404 in this scenario for some reason or I'm misunderstanding how `TestRestTemplate` is working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TestRestTemplate` is, by design, fault tolerant. This means that it doesn't throw exceptions when an error response (400 or greater) is received. This makes it easier to test error scenarios as, rather than having to catch an exception, you can simply assert that the response's status code, body, headers, etc are as expected for the scenario in question.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Sounds like a minor documentation bug then. If I want to interrogate the result of my PUT, should I switch to calling `exchange` rather than `put`?

Comment: Yes, if you care about the response, you should use exchange for a `PUT` request